# YouTube Firefox app

Tags: firefox, youtube

Running a brand new installation of Ubuntu 13.04 I downloaded today and installed via a Live USB.
First action was to open Firefox. Well, no, I closed it because the updater had 100 MB of updates. Cool, installed them. Restarted.
After updating and restarting, my first action was to launch Firefox.
Into the URL bar I typed in "youtube" + <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

From the top of the Firefox UI, pops a message telling me "for the best experience, install the YouTube app."
I installed it. After all, it looked like 'official' `Firefox-for-Ubuntu` software.

1. What the heck does this "program" do?
   The only effect I see so far is a new icon on my launcher.
2. How can I uninstall this?

I went genocidal and disabled every single one of the four (!!) Ubuntu/Unity Firefox add-ons, and that fixed it. But what an awful design decision! What a horrible attempt at a program! It even shares traits with **malware** -- there is NO listed way to uninstall or remove it.

I truly **can** see how this might be useful for those users who have trouble distinguishing web site-hosted *applications* and local executables, but I seriously expected more from the combined brainpower of Ubuntu and Firefox. Sheezus.

Comment: The Ubuntu Firefox Modifications extension gives firefox a native look in ubuntu. And websites integration lets you control webapps from desktop. Like controlling media buttons on some music websites from the sound menu, etc. While it may not be useful for everyone, I think its cool that they're trying to improve the integration of the core apps with the desktop. And I think (not sure) when the extensions are enabled, options appear in firefox preferences dialog to disable websites integration. Malware? What you have is not just Firefox but Firefox for Ubuntu Canonical - check "About Firefox".

Comment: Yes, what I have is Firefox for Canonical. All the more reason for it to not to behave like malware. Installing something and then not providing an obvious way to uninstall it is malware-like behavior. Not to mention amateurish program writing. I just expected more from Canonical/Mozilla.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had problems with that app on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. It caused the OS to completely freeze up. To uninstall it , I entered the following commands in the terminal:

```
dpkg -l | grep -i youtube (to get name of the package)
sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-youtube ('unity-webapps-youtube' being the package name)
```